# How to use performance.measure in firefox,

Tags: javascript, performance, browser, webapi

When I run this simple code in console :

```
performance.mark('start-mark');
performance.mark('stop-mark');

performance.measure('name','start-mark','stop-mark');
```

performance.measure returns PerformanceMeasure object (as in documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/measure). The problem is that everything works fine in chrome, edge and safari. Unfortunately in firefox it reutrns *undefined*.

Beside documentation I checked also in caniuse.com and it should work.

Can you help me to run this "code" in firefox (version 93 - actual).

Comment: I'm able to replicate your results. Appears to be a bug in Firefox but I can't find it in their [bug tracker](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/). This has been [previously asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69434426/performance-api-not-working-partially-in-firefox) but no answer and there's at least [one software project](https://review.discourse.org/t/dev-disable-upload-instrumentation-if-performance-measure-returns-undefined-14427/24979) that's had to work around it.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a known implementation inconsistency in Firefox.

From [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/measure#browser_compatibility](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9p9D1.png)):

[image: A table showing browser compatibility and indicating that Firefox returns undefined]

I worked around this using [Performance.getEntriesByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/getEntriesByName):

```js
performance.mark('start-mark');
performance.mark('stop-mark');
performance.measure('name', 'start-mark', 'stop-mark');

console.log(performance.getEntriesByName('name', 'measure')[0]);
```